# How to execute native binaries from Atom Package?

Tags: atom-editor

I want to write the package, that have to run a program inside - with arguments. It's better to be cross-platform, but the Linux-only solution is good enough.

How to do that in Atom Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BufferedProcess](https://atom.io/docs/api/latest/BufferedProcess) to spawn any binary you want.

```
{BufferedProcess} = require 'atom'

command = 'ps'
args = ['-ef']
stdout = (output) -> console.log(output)
exit = (code) -> console.log("ps -ef exited with #{code}")
process = new BufferedProcess({command, args, stdout, exit})
```